# Load a ResourceBundle over HTTP?

Tags: java, spring, resourcebundle

I have a requirement to load text labels from our CMS. The content is exposed in standard properties file format. The CMS operates as a sort of RESTful web service provider as opposed to pushing files, so I would need to pull properties files on demand. I was naively hoping that if I created a ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource and set the basename to the URL of the file minus the locale parameter, that this would work like magic, but evidently it doesn't. Can anyone suggest an approach to this? Is there an out-of-the-box solution in Spring or is there some class that I would need to extend?

Comment: Looking at the source for `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`, I think it *should* work for HTTP URLs. How did you configure it?

Comment: It looks like you're correct. I did some snooping in wireshark and it is, in fact, hitting the CMS although it's appending ".properties" which is the problem. Looks like it requires that suffix (or .xml) and it won't be easy to cure it with a subclass. I'll try to configure the CMS to support it. Should I delete this question?

Comment: You could delete it, or you could wait until you get it working, then add an answer yourself. It's still a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, skaffman's comment was correct. My web service was just expecting the locale as a GET param (locale=en_US), but was getting a file suffix (ie, locale=_en_US.properties). So, it was as simple matter of stripping the extra stuff from the param and it actually works fine.